# Show that a function analytic on $ R =\{z:-\frac{\pi}{4} < \arg z < \frac{\pi}{4} \}$ and continuous on $\bar{R}$ is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this following question in complex analysis:

> Lef $f$ be an analytic function on $ R =\{z:-\frac{\pi}{4} < \arg z < \frac{\pi}{4} \}$, continuous on $\bar{R}$, $|f(z)|\leq1$ for all $ z \in \partial R$, and $ \lim_{z \to \infty \choose z\in R}f(z) = c $ when $|c| \leq 1$. 
> Prove that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $ z \in R$

I have seen a similar question by my instructor that uses a function $ g $ that involves $f$ in it and makes the assumptions of the maximum modulus principle. However, he told me that there is no need for such a function. 
My idea was to "bound" the set $R$ with $D_r = R \cap \{z : |z|\leq r \}$, and to show that $f$ makes the assumption of  the maximum modulus principle on $r > \delta$ for some $\delta>0$, and for that I need to show that $|f|\leq 1$ on $\partial D_r$. I think that this is where the limit of the function is at work here, for example $|f(z)|\leq |f(z)-c| +|c|$, but I'm not sure how. 
I could really use some help in this, I've been stuck with it for quite a while.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $z_0 \in R$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. If $r > |z_0|$ is sufficiently large then
$$
|f(z)| \le |c| + |f(z) - c| \le |c| + \epsilon \le 1 + \epsilon
$$
for all $z \in R$ with $|z| = r$. It follows that $|f(z)| \le 1+\epsilon$ for all $z \in \partial D_r$, and the maximum modulus principle  gives that $|f(z_0)| \le 1 + \epsilon$.

This holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, therefore $|f(z_0)| \le 1$.

*Remarks:*

- The conclusion still holds if $|c| >1$, or more generally, if $f$ is bounded in $R$.

  This can be seen by considering the functions $g_a(z) = f(z)/(1+az)$ with $a > 0$. Then $|g_a(z)| \le 1$ on the boundary of $R$, and $\lim\limits_{z\to \infty, z\in R} g_a(z) = 0$. It follows that  $|g_a(z)| \le 1$ in $R$, and taking the limit $a \to 0$ gives the conclusion.
- An even more general result is the [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle), which shows that $f$ is bounded in a sector if it is bounded on the boundary of the sector and does not “grow too fast.”

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed that. It's an argument that is even used in calculus... thank you very much!

Comment: @LagrangeLover: You are welcome. – Note that the conclusion also holds if $|c| > 1$, or if $f$ is bounded, or even if $f$ does not “grow too fast.” That is a bit more work, see [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragmén–Lindelöf_principle).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that there was an actual "famous" theorem for cases like mine. Thanks for that!